# Excel, how to make a for loop?

Tags: excel, for-loop, if-statement

I have this code here:

```
=C5
-(IF(G9="C",(IF(G10=0,$C2,$C2-G10)),))
-(IF(H9="C",(IF(H10=0,$C2,$C2-H10)),))
-(IF(I9="C",(IF(I10=0,$C2,$C2-I10)),))
```

etc...

It continuates from G9 to J9.

Is there a way to make it with less code? In java I would have used a for loop, but I don't know how to do it with Excel

Thanks!!

Comment: this If: `IF(G10=0,$C2,$C2-G10)` does not make sense.  If G10 is `0` then `$C2-G10` will return the same as `$C2` as any number minus `0` is that number.

Comment: the problem is with the paid free days. C5 is the total number of the free paid days, C2 is the number of hours worked each day. The problem is: if the employee writes "C", this employee used C2 hours of his free paid days. BUT, if this employee only used for example 3 hours this day, I need to do C2-G10 (number of hours by day MINUS number of hours worked this day)

Answer (score 1):

Use SUMPRODUCT:

```
=C5-SUMRPODUCT((G9:J9="C")*($C2-G10:J10))
```

Comment: I tested this: =SUMPRODUCT(G9:J9="C"), and, G9="C", and it returns me 0

Comment: that is because to do that you would use: `=SUMPRODUCT(--(G9:J9="C"))`